# Use Polly to retry api request if the status code is not equal to 200 OK

Tags: c#, .net, api, httpwebresponse, polly

I am trying to use Polly to handle status codes other than 200 OK so that it retries the API request.

However, I am struggling to understand how to Polly to swallow an exception and then execute a retry. This is what I currently have, but it is not syntactically correct:

```
var policy = Policy.HandleResult<HttpStatusCode>(r => r == HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout)
                                                        .Retry(5);
        HttpWebResponse response;

        policy.Execute(() => 
        {
            response = SendRequestToInitialiseApi(url);
        });
```

In the execution, I need the response to also be assigned to a variable to be used elsewhere in the method.

The return type of the response is a 'HttpWebResponse' and when I get a '504' for instance, it throws an exception.

Any help/feedback would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: If it throws an exception instead of returning the status code, you would also likely want a `.Handle<FooException>()` or `.Or<FooException>()` clause in the policy (where `FooException` is the type of exception thrown).  The Polly readme has examples of the `.Handle<FooException>()` or `.Or<FooException>()` syntax, including how to refine this to handle the exception only under certain conditions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set Polly Retry for the set specific StatusCodes only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61019007/how-to-set-polly-retry-for-the-set-specific-statuscodes-only)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type you provide to `HandleResult` must be the same type you want to return from the execution, which in your case is an `HttpWebResponse` since you want to make use of this value later.

**Edit:** I've added in exception handling as suggested by **mountain traveller**

```cs
var policy = Policy
    // Handle any `HttpRequestException` that occurs during execution.
    .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
    // Also consider any response that doesn't have a 200 status code to be a failure.
    .OrResult<HttpWebResponse>(r => r.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    .Retry(5);

// Execute the request within the retry policy and return the `HttpWebResponse`.
var response = policy.Execute(() => SendRequestToInitialiseApi(url));

// Do something with the response.
```